# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Why does this statement succeed?

```
    SELECT CAST('08:50' as time)
```

But this one fails? `tmrec` is an nvarchar(6) column and contains the same value `'08:50'`. This is making me crazy since last 1 hour.

```
    SELECT   TOP 1 CAST(tmrec as time) 
    FROM     Instr 
    WHERE    igrp = 'JD' 
    ORDER BY ino , smallin
```

[This screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/f5wtcbr91/) shows the 1st query's result. It contains 08:50. Yet the 2nd query throws error.

**Edit:**

Even this doesn't work which guarantees that conversion is applied only on fetched records:

```
    SELECT CAST( tmrec as time)
    FROM
         (
            SELECT TOP 1 tmrec
            FROM   [ccwise-courts].[dbo].[INSTR]
            WHERE  igrp = 'JD' 
            ORDER BY ino , smallin
         ) v
```

Comment: I have to ask, why store "date" and "time" values as strings, instead of as ... dates and times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, to look for bad data, you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT TOP(100) '-->' + REPLACE(tmrec, ' ', '*') + '<--bad'
FROM Instr
WHERE ISDATE(tmrec) = 0
```

And if you **still** cannot make it out, you can list out the specific ASCII code of the characters involved (here I go up to 6 per the question):

```
SELECT TOP(100) '-->' + REPLACE(tmrec, ' ', '*') + '<--bad',
  Char1 = ascii(substring(tmrec,1,1)),
  Char2 = ascii(substring(tmrec,2,1)),
  Char3 = ascii(substring(tmrec,3,1)),
  Char4 = ascii(substring(tmrec,4,1)),
  Char5 = ascii(substring(tmrec,5,1)),
  Char6 = ascii(substring(tmrec,6,1))
FROM Instr
WHERE ISDATE(tmrec) = 0
```

There is this [Connect item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) that deals with SQL Server processing CAST on the SELECT clause before the WHERE filter has been applied.  To overcome that, as also noted in the bug report, you can use a CASE statement:

```
CAST(CASE WHEN ISDATE(tmrec)=1 THEN tmrec END as time)
```

Comment: I understand but what I don't understand is why would '08:50' doesn't work.

Comment: That row and column tmrec contains the same value '08:50'. I'll post screenshot in few mins.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: I get 48,56,58,53,48,NULL for tmrec field.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi: Yes, correct. I replaced the 2nd query in screenshot with the ascii functions that you suggested.

Comment: Can't say how happy I am because I am pretty much sure without SO I couldn't never have been able to understand why it is failing :p. I would have kept banging my head against wall.